# ssh connect do not use identity from config

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I am trying to setup ssh connection to gitlab.com. I have corresponding identity file and it works if I use it explicitly. But failed when I expect it read identity file from config.

Here explicit usage:

```
ssh -v -i /root/.ssh/reshop-deploy -T git@gitlab.com
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.com [52.167.219.168] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/reshop-deploy type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/reshop-deploy-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to gitlab.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:HbW3g8zUjNSksFbqTiUWPWg2Bq1x8xdGUrliXFzSnUw
debug1: Host 'gitlab.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:36
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/reshop-deploy
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to gitlab.com ([52.167.219.168]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: PTY allocation disabled.
Welcome to GitLab, XXXX!
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 2880, received 2776 bytes, in 0.4 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 6778.9, received 6534.1
debug1: Exit status 0
```

But if I run it with hope on /root/.ssh/config I got:

```
ssh -v -T git@gitlab.com
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.com [52.167.219.168] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to gitlab.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:HbW3g8zUjNSksFbqTiUWPWg2Bq1x8xdGUrliXFzSnUw
debug1: Host 'gitlab.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:36
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

.ssh folder list:

```
ls -al /root/.ssh/
total 60
drwxr-x---  2 root root  4096 Apr 25 17:54 .
drwx------ 11 root root  4096 Apr 25 18:01 ..
-rw-------  1 root root  5024 Jun 13  2016 authorized_keys
-rw-------  1 root root   193 Apr 25 17:48 config
-rw-------  1 root root  1675 Dec  4  2015 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 13991 Apr 25 16:59 known_hosts
-rw-------  1 root root  3243 Apr 25 14:40 reshop-deploy
```

Here it is config content:

```
cat /root/.ssh/config 
Host gitlab
    Hostname gitlab.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/reshop-deploy
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Seems it ignores Identity file, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Your question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `~/.ssh/config` configuration begins with `Host gitlab`.  That means that all of the configuration directives after it, up to the next `Host` line, will only take effect if you refer to the server exactly as "`gitlab`" on the command line, e.g., `ssh gitlab`.  If you also want your configuration to apply when doing `ssh gitlab.com` or `ssh git@gitlab.com`, then you need to change your `Host` line to `Host gitlab gitlab.com`.